# VS Code flags System.out.print

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, linter

I'm a beginner programmer and It bothers me - why VS Code continues to flag my `System.out.print` statements and suggests using `logger` when in most places and tutorials they tell you to use `out.print` as a basic output stream?

[Problem with System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtxJS.png)

[out problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIB4U.png)

Comment: `System.out` is, for several reasons, a bad pick for a **real app**. VSC just assumes you are doing something real and proper here and not toying around, hence the linter warning. You can safely ignore it for now - but start to consider it once you are doing a non-toy project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can surely use System.out although a logger has so much more capabilities and is therefore better for a bigger project. If you just plan to make some small things, you don't need to use a logger if you don't want to, otherwise I'd highly recommend using one